# Will I be able to return to Amsterdam to retrieve my lost residence permit?

Tags: visas, schengen, residency

I had lost my wallet at the Amsterdam airport which had my residence permit, issued by a country in the Schengen area. I realized it only when I reached my destination. Luckily, the authorities found my wallet and my residence permit. The problem is that it is with the authorities in Amsterdam, while I am in Dubai. When I spoke with the authorities, they told me I can travel to Amsterdam and tell the Immigration officer that my residence permit is with them.

Still, I am worried that the airline won't let me check in without it. I do have a duplicate copy.

UPDATE:

The Lost and Found department has found my wallet and now the immigration officers have my residence permit.

A big lesson learnt : Even though you lose your IMPORTANT PROPERTY in an airport, try to contact the lost and found department of the airports to check if they have your lost property.

Comment: Do you mean your passport? I am not aware of any paper Schengen visas.

Comment: Sorry the ID Card which is given as the visa in the schengen countries :) and not the passport

Comment: Ah, okay so your permanent resident card was lost. You need to show a copy of your card, or if your passport still has  visa, that would suffice or simply a confirmation from the authorities in Amsterdam (like an email) that you can travel.

Comment: Thank you very much @BurhanKhalid ! I really appreciate it

Comment: Technically, this card is a “residence permit”. Using the most accurate terminology might prevent some misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes true @Relaxed!! I will edit for the convenience

Comment: Which country issued your residence permit?

Comment: What documents did you show when you left the Schengen area? In other words, how did you leave without your residence permit?

Comment: As suggested in the linked duplicate question, buy a ticket *via* Amsterdam to a third country which doesn't require a visa for citizens of your country. Then proceed to exit at AMS instead. Although it may get tricky if you need an airport transit visa.

Comment: @JonathanReez am afraid the cases are different here. In my case, residence permit is found and the immigration officers have it.  So they suggested me to enter Amsterdam and then contact them so that I can have my residence permit back.  My only worry was whether the airlines here at dubai, will allow me to travel with my duplicate (Photocopy) residence permit.

Comment: @phoog I lost my permit only few minutes before boarding the flight :( Since there was a queue, I didnt notice my wallet missing. but luckily they found it the next day.!

Comment: @WannabeTraveller I am afraid airlines wont let to board the flight without your visa. Call the embassy and see if they can issue emergency visa to visit Netherlands to collect your card.

Comment: The airline won't care. The easiest way is to use the trick from the linked post.